# How to construct a minimum bound box tuple for each geometry in a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas GeoDataFrame of lakes. I am trying to create a new column named 'MBB' with the bounding box for each lake.

I am using the `bounds` function from `GeoPandas`. However, this function exports `minx`, `miny`, `maxx`, and `maxy` in four separate columns.

```
# Preview the Use of the .bounds method to ensure it is exporting properly
lakes_a['geometry'].bounds
```

| minx | miny | maxx | maxy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -69.37 | 44.19 | -69.36 | 44.20 |
| -69.33 | 44.19 | -69.33 | 44.19 |

My desired output would look like the below and be able to be reinserted into the `GeoPandasDataFrame`

| MBB |
| --- |
| (-69.37, 44.19, -69.36, 44.20) |
| (-69.33, 44.19, -69.33, 44.19) |

My gut tells me that I need to use either `shapely.Geometry.Polygon` or `shapely.Geometry.box`

The Polygon data used to create these is as follows.

Note: This is my first time working with GeoPandas (and new to Python as well); please forgive me if I made any mistakes :)

```
POLYGON Z ((-69.37232840276027 44.202966598054786 0, -69.37216940276056 44.202966598054786 0, -69.37181966942774 44.20276073138842 0, -69.37156540276146 44.20154879805699 0, -69.37092960276249 44.20138873139058 0, -69.370580002763 44.20111433139101 0, -69.37051640276309 44.20049693139197 0, -69.37042106942994 44.20042833139206 0, -69.37038926942995 44.20015393139249 0, -69.37013506943038 44.19976513139312 0, -69.36969020276439 44.19939919806035 0, -69.36838700276638 44.19903333139422 0, -69.36800546943368 44.198827531394556 0, -69.36787826943385 44.19864459806149 0, -69.3678466694339 44.19784419806274 0, -69.36797380276704 44.1973183313969 0, -69.36876860276584 44.19663233139795 0, -69.36759246943433 44.19658639806471 0, -69.3667658694356 44.1971809980638 0, -69.36641646943616 44.19722673139705 0, -69.36597146943683 44.19695219806414 0, -69.36549480277091 44.196403398065 0, -69.36470006943881 44.19583173139921 0, -69.36425520277282 44.19562593139955 0, -69.3618714694432 44.19500819806717 0, -69.36158546944364 44.19471099806759 0, -69.36152220277705 44.193887798068886 0, -69.36066406944508 44.19363613140263 0, -69.3604098027788 44.19345319806956 0, -69.3604098027788 44.193270198069854 0, -69.36066420277837 44.192995798070285 0, -69.36069540277833 44.19279379807057 0, -69.36069600277835 44.19278999807062 0, -69.36082306944479 44.19276719807061 0, -69.36098206944456 44.19237839807124 0, -69.3623808694424 44.19091499807348 0, -69.36288200277494 44.19074539807377 0, -69.36292126944159 44.19073213140712 0, -69.36342966944079 44.19084653140692 0, -69.36371580277364 44.191029531406684 0, -69.3639380027733 44.19198999807185 0, -69.36419220277293 44.19217279807157 0, -69.36451000277242 44.192195731404865 0, -69.36520940277131 44.191784131405484 0, -69.36587680277029 44.19157833140582 0, -69.3665442694359 44.19157853140581 0, -69.36733886943472 44.191761398072174 0, -69.36772020276743 44.19199013140519 0, -69.36791080276714 44.192516131404375 0, -69.368006002767 44.19256193140427 0, -69.36803786943364 44.19281339807054 0, -69.36845100276634 44.192767598070645 0, -69.36861000276605 44.19210453140499 0, -69.3694046027648 44.19155559807251 0, -69.36997680276392 44.1913039980729 0, -69.37058060276303 44.19118973140644 0, -69.37340926942528 44.19130413140624 0, -69.37448980275695 44.191601331405764 0, -69.37506200275607 44.19155559807251 0, -69.37541146942215 44.191326931406195 0, -69.37579286942156 44.19137273140615 0, -69.3759200027547 44.19146413140601 0, -69.37588826942141 44.19208153140505 0, -69.37534800275563 44.19322493140328 0, -69.37525260275572 44.19397959806872 0, -69.37541166942219 44.19436839806815 0, -69.37582466942155 44.19489433140069 0, -69.37633326942074 44.19521439806681 0, -69.37671466942015 44.19532873139997 0, -69.37798606941817 44.19532859806668 0, -69.37817680275123 44.19542013139983 0, -69.37801800275145 44.19578599806596 0, -69.37757286941883 44.19601473139892 0, -69.3765240027538 44.19601473139892 0, -69.37601546942125 44.19628913139849 0, -69.37557046942192 44.196723598064466 0, -69.37531620275564 44.1972039313971 0, -69.37528446942235 44.198598798061596 0, -69.37544340275548 44.19921619806064 0, -69.37582486942154 44.199970931392784 0, -69.37588846942145 44.20049679805862 0, -69.37607920275445 44.2009541980579 0, -69.37607926942115 44.20184593138987 0, -69.37582486942154 44.20223473138924 0, -69.37493486942293 44.2030807980546 0, -69.3744898694236 44.20337813138747 0, -69.37394946942442 44.20351539805392 0, -69.37340920275864 44.20351539805392 0, -69.37293226942603 44.2031037980546 0, -69.37232840276027 44.202966598054786 0))
```

```
POLYGON Z ((-69.33154920282357 44.19536753139994 0, -69.33170806948999 44.195504798066395 0, -69.3318348694898 44.19584779806587 0, -69.33212086948936 44.196076598065474 0, -69.33224780282251 44.196396798064995 0, -69.3329150028215 44.19676293139776 0, -69.33291466948816 44.19706019806398 0, -69.33278746948832 44.19726599806364 0, -69.33211986948936 44.19733433139686 0, -69.33103926949104 44.19719673139707 0, -69.3307216028249 44.19701373139736 0, -69.33069020282494 44.19653339806479 0, -69.33046780282524 44.19630473139847 0, -69.33046800282528 44.1960073980656 0, -69.33094520282452 44.195458798066454 0, -69.33154920282357 44.19536753139994 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html):

```py
pd.Series(
    lakes_a['geometry'].bounds.to_records(index=False),
    index=lakes_a.index,
)
```